# Best way to dynamically display news articles (text, images)? Other than WebView?

Tags: android, html

I'm writing an Android app that reads `RSS` feeds, fetches `HTML` articles, processes the article's `HTML` to only store the important stuff (story body, including paragraphs and images/image captions, etc), and **display it to the user**.

I've done everything except for the final step.

The articles will obviously have varying text, varying image positions, etc. and I want to be able to **preserve the order** of those elements (as they were when fetched).

What is the best way to implement this? I don't really want to use a `WebView`...

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Please see comments of accepted answer for my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I could see to do something like this would be to escape each of the html tags and handle each appropriately. Assuming your not interested interested in the head element and metadata you could do something like the pseudo code below for the following html page

```
<html>  
...
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<h1> some text probably your title </h1>
<p1> first paragraph </p1>
<p2> second paragraph </p2>
<img src='/some_url' title='some_title'>
</body> 
</html>
```

Now for what you need to do also note that how the html page is actually set up will depend on webpage/rss feed so modifications may will probably be need to be made for many sites none the less you'll want to do something like this: Not when i say llok for I mean some how search for substring (java if on device) anything you wish off device

```
  find("<body>") everything before can be thrown away
  find ("<img" or "<p1" or "<h1" or "<div") handle accordingly
```

(more then likely this will change on source of page)

```
     but for say <p1 found 

     find (">") represents end of tag attribute pull all of this until delimiter tag "</p1>"
```

there you've got your first paragraph
for image tag

```
    ie. find("<img")
    then find("title=") or find("src=")
```

the substring after these will be The image title and source file for the image      respectively not that these values will be wrapped in one of `'` or `"`

This isn't a complete solution but hey I have seen what you've tried so its a starting point

Comment: Thanks for your input! The problem I'm having is deciding the best way to display the articles. I parsed them fine! Thanks though, I appreciate it.

Comment: My, mistake I really didn't understand that from your question is there something wrong with dynamically mapping them to a view in android in the order found?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm still a noob when it comes to Android UI programming. So, it's possible to generate, maintain and manage views that change at runtime?

Comment: Yes it most certainly is it's a bit trickier then doing this with say html and javascript but it can indeed be done check out this simple tutorial (just adding buttons) http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/ or this one which has dynamically added text and buttons http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html if you need more help... you know where to turn!

Comment: @brendosthoughts Hi, i want to dynamically display texts and images (in-between) like news article, the data can be hard-coded. in which format i've to save the data and how to  display it? Thank you